# How to KVO observing of whiteBalanceMode property of AVCaptureDevice?

Tags: ios, swift4, key-value-observing

Apple says the properties `whiteBalanceMode` and `exposureMode` of `AVCaptureDevice` are KVO observable.

This is my first time programming in Swift, after a decade working in Objective-C.

KVO appears to be way more complex in Swift.

I have tried this:

```
var kvoWhiteBalanceObserving : NSKeyValueObservation?
@objc var capDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
```

later on...

```
capDevice = captureDevice

self.kvoWhiteBalanceObserving = observe(\.capDevice.whiteBalanceMode, options: [.old, .new]) { object, change in
        print(object.whiteBalanceMode)
}
```

Xcode points to the `\.` saying:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

How to I KVO this in swift 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

observe like this:

```
self.kvoWhiteBalanceObserving = capDevice?.observe(\.whiteBalanceMode, options: [.old, .new]) { object, change in
    print(object.whiteBalanceMode)
}
```